# Is it safe to change web server root directory to owners root:www-data with 775 rights?

Tags: php, linux, apache, access-rights

I had a problem with the PHP fwrite function not writing anything and I figured it was because of rights.

One apache process is run by root and several others by www-data:

> $ ps -aux |grep apache
>   root     21239  0.0  0.3 222104 26524 ?        Ss   02:31   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
>   www-data 21240  0.0  0.1 222316 13736 ?        S    02:31   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
>   ...

The web root directory was owned by root:root with no write rights for the group owner (755):

> /var/www# ls -l
>   drwxr-xr-x 9 root                  root                  4096 Feb 29 02:11 html

So I changed the group owner of the root directory to www-data and granted write rights:

> /var/www# chown root:www-data html
>   /var/www# chmod 775 html
>   /var/www# ls -l
>   drwxrwxr-x 9 root                  www-data              4096 Feb 29 02:11 html

Now it worked. My question is if this is a proper and - most important - secure setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because Apache runs as `www-data` in Ubuntu. But, if you would download the source code and compile it, it will run as the user `daemon`. The folders that Apache uses should be owned by the user Apache runs as.

So, if you would need to change the Apache's default user and group change/add the line:

```
User <your-username> # (Without angle-bracket)
Group <your-group> # (Without angle-bracket), this setting is usually the same as the user
```

You cannot write using PHP beacause you are using the php module in apache. If you would use PHP-FPM, then you would have to change the default user and group in PHP-FPM's www.conf file. You are not using PHP-FPM by the info you have given, hence, when you change Apache's user and Group, it is also applied to PHP, as PHP is running in Apache. If you have a lot of visitors, and your website needs to be faster, then, enable PHP-FPM by doing the following:

1) Unload the mod_php(version-number) by running:

```
sudo a2dismod php(version-number)
```

(Optional Step) 2) You might need to use mpm_event and unload mpm_prefork. You might see a weird message saying conflict and stuff, but ignore it. You can do it by running:

```
sudo a2dismod prefork && sudo a2enmod event
```

3) Install PHP-FPM:

```
sudo apt install php(version-number)-fpm && sudo service php(version-number)-fpm start
```

4) Enable proxy_fcgi module in Apache:

```
sudo a2enmod proxy_fcgi
```

5) Add the following to apache2.conf file:

```
<FilesMatch "\.ph(p[2-6]?|tml)$">
SetHandler "proxy:fcgi://localhost:9000"
</FilesMatch>
```

6) Run:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

And you're done!